# mvc render partial view without httpContext or controller context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to render partial view without ViewContext or ControllerContext?

- I'm trying to get PartialView Html as string from outside of Controller Action.
- OR
- Is it possible to call Controller Action from another method? (this will allow me to execute controller action and get partial view html this way).

Comment: Are you trying to call this from some kind of background task or something (with no httpcontext whatsoever)? I have code I use in a base controller which will render a partial view to a string for use with AJAX/JSON or for emailing, etc, but nothing to generate this out of nowhere as I haven't needed to.

Comment: yes. it's a background task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the [Razor Generator](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx) Visual Studio Extension. Basically you run the custom tool on your view and it will generate a class that you can pass a model into and it will generate a string.

Comment: I gave up on using ViewContext in signalR. it turns out that even though signalR allows for readonly access to session context sometimes it will be set to null. I've used Razor Generator as suggested by Britton. The only con to using it is that I have to have two different views (my partialView) that I use in MVC and another for RazorGenerator to use which is pretty much redundant. thanks